# Get some information on a string with split and substring

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have to get information of latitude and longitude from the string filePos.
I have to put this information into an array(called beaches), so it must be:

```
var beaches = [
                  ["45.411158", "11.906326", 1]// 1 is the index
                  ["45.411190", "11.906324", 2]// 2 is the index
              ]
```

I tried to do that, but eclipse show me this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

```
var filePos = "{'Data':'17/02/2015', 'Descrizione':'PROVA AAA', 'Lat':'45.411158', 'Lng':'11.906326', 'Foto':'sdjahvas'}" +
            "{'Data':'18/02/2015', 'Descrizione':'PROVA BAA', 'Lat':'45.411190', 'Lng':'11.906324', 'Foto':'asde'}";

var beaches = filePos.split("}") // Break up the original string on `", "`
.map(function(element, index){
    var temp = element.split(', ');
    lat = temp[2].substr(7, temp[2].length -2);
    lng = temp[3].substr(7, temp[3].length -2);
    return [lat, lng, index + 1];
}); 

console.log(beaches);
alert(JSON.stringify(beaches));
```

Comment: Why don't you convert the data to a valid JSON? Replace all `'` with `"` and then use `JSON.parse`

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you try to achieve, but try to check first if temp[2] and temp[3] is not undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the object string into valid json and parse it, you can just iterate over the object.

```
var jsonString = filePos.replace(/\'/g, '"').split('}'),
    positionAry;
jsonString.pop();
positionAry = JSON.parse('[' + jsonString.join('},') + '}]');
beaches = positionAry.map(function (obj) {
    return [obj.Lat, obj.Lng];
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, now eclipse show me an error ('06-25 15:20:34.470: I/chromium(28285): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (1)'
) In Index.html at line 1 I have <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Fixed the code, there was an extra empty element in the array created by split('}') so the initial JSON was malformed.